# Is there a way to reproduce microphone action of the microphone button in the iOS keyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, dictation

I want to add a microphone button next to a textFiled.
This button should activate the dictation mode of the iOS keyboard, exactly as the microphone button in the keyboard does.
It's easier to see a microphone button next to a textField than at the bottom of the keyboard.

[image: keyboard]

I know there is some similar post saying it's impossible, but they are 5 years old, maybe there is some new api since this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to pragmatically trigger the keyboard into dictation mode.

You'll need to build something yourself using `SFSpeechRecognizer` if you want to convert speech to text.